# How to structure nested nodes that need updating in d3 v4 force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 v4 and would like to do the nested selections like in this jsfiddle (but in a force layout with circles not text in a table): https://jsfiddle.net/nwozjscs/2/

I'm not sure where to start. My data looks like this [["circle1", "circle2"],["circle3", "circle4"],["circle5", "circle6"],["circle7", "circle8"]]. I would like to have a circle for every mini array and then append the circles inside that just above that circle in the force layout. The data is changing so I need the exit enter merge cycle for both the big data set of mini arrays and for each mini array. Are there any examples of nested selection in d3 v4 force layout? Where should I start with this?

Here is what I currently have however this doesn't append the small red circles at all and the updating doesn't seem to work.

```
// Create circle nodes
this.circleNode = this.d3Graph.selectAll("circle")

// Call our restartD3 function
this.restartD3();


// Function that restarts D3 and replace nodes with new this.users array (needed in when  add or remove a node)
restartD3() {

  // Circles
this.circleNode = this.circleNode.data(this.users);

 this.circleNode.exit().remove();

//maybe append a group here not circles
  this.rowenter = this.circleNode
  .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circlenodes")
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("fill", "green")



  this.cell = this.circleNode.merge(this.rowenter)
  .selectAll(".circlenodes").data(function(d){
    return d.m;});

     this.cell.exit().remove();

    this.cell.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "smallnodes")
    .attr("r", function(d){
      return 10
  })
  .attr("fill", "red")


  this.force.nodes(this.users);


}
```

Comment: You have two questions here: how to set an enter/exit/update selection for the nested data and how to create a force layout with it. This is too broad for me (and probably for many others). I suggest you just keep the first part of the question and drop the force part (also because you didn't say how the nodes should be linked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: A better solution using a proper nested join

So this got me thinking more - I didn't particularly like this approach in that the `innerRender` has to do lots of joins rather than a single big join. Felt like it could be improved. So it turns out that the `selection.data` function can also take a function which I hadn't realised before. (If you've not come across the page yet recommend reading https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/ ).

So I've modified my example - this is the render function. I've also added some transitions so visually it's easier to see what's going on.

```
render = (data) => {
const join = d3
    .select(".container")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data);

// Remove old groups
join
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("transform", "scale(0)")
    .remove();

// Create the new groups
const groups = join
    .enter()
    .append("g");

// Add in the new circles
groups.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 0)
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("r", RADIUS);

// Merge the new groups with the existing groups
// and apply an appropriate translation
const innerJoin = groups
    .merge(join)
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
    .selectAll("circle.inner")
    .data(d => d);

// Remove old small circles
innerJoin
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("r", 0);

 const newCircles = innerJoin
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("class", "inner")
     .attr("r", 0)
     .style("fill", "orange")
     .attr("cy", -RADIUS - 5);

 newCircles
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("r", 5);

 newCircles.merge(join)
     .attr("cx", (d, i) => 2 * i * 5);
}
```

See the full example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/m0kqawf7/3/)

---

I recommend breaking this up into separate functions. Start with the regular `d3.forceSimulation` for the outer part - handling the join on the outer arrays and the forces being applied. Here's an example of how I'd do that render.

```
render = (data) => {
    const join = d3
        .select(".container")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data);

    // Remove old
    join.exit().remove();

    // Create the new groups
    const groups = join.enter().append("g");
    groups.append("circle")
        .attr("r", RADIUS)
        .style("fill", "steelblue");

    // Merge the new groups with the existing groups
    // and apply an appropriate translation
    groups.merge(join)
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
        .each(function(d) {
            renderInner(this, d);
        });
}
```

Notice the call to `renderInner`? That's where I'd deal with the nesting, keeping it simple so actually you just treat it as another render...

```
renderInner = (element, data) => {
    const join = d3
        .select(element)
        .selectAll("circle.inner")
        .data(data);

     join.exit().remove();
     join.enter()
         .append("circle")
         .attr("r", 5)
         .style("fill", "orange")
         .attr("cy", -RADIUS - 5)
         .merge(join)
         .attr("cx", (d, i) => 2 * i * 5);
};
```

Here's an example that I put together to fully illustrate. If you wanted to it'd be really easy to map out those `inner` items to be fed into the `nodes` function on the `forceSimulation` so that they behave in the force too.

Here's a fully working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/m0kqawf7/)

Comment: This structure works great. Thank you! I am having one problems however: Performance is bad with more than 20 mini and big circles. The circles are constantly moving in my simulation, and it gets choppier the more circles added. I'm assuming this is because render is being called 60 times per second onTic. I there a way to improve this? Maybe only call the whole render function when a node is added or subtracted and have a basic positioning function that moves the circles around 60fps

Comment: Yeah indeed, what you've suggested is exactly how I'd do it - I was just trying to demo the join when short on time. Stick a class on each `<g>` and select them all within a tick function, just update their transform.

Comment: @PurplePanda So I've updated this answer - I wasn't quite happy and came across an important discovery. I've also modified that tick in my latest sample code.

Comment: @PurplePanda just wondering if this answered your original question?

Comment: Yes. I got it working. Thank you for all of your help. I'll ask this as another question if I can't figure it out on my own, but I figure I'll pick your brain in case it's an easy fix. So the big circle and the little circles actually have to be in separate groups because the little circles always need to be on top of every big circle, so got rid of the current big circle and just ad that as a separate node unattached to the little circles. This works well and little circles are always on top of the big circle, except when little circles are overlapping with the top left quadrant of a big circ

Comment: The little circles will be behind the other big circle and then as soon as they move past away from the top left quadrant of the big circle they will pop back infront

Comment: Might need a little more explanation. If you get stuck ask another question and post a link to it here in the comments and I'll try to take a look